# Why telegram bot doesn't conflict with nginx?

Tags: python, linux, telegram-bot

I wrote a simple telegram bot and it works great without conflicting with my firewall. But my question is this, in the firewall I have ports 80 and 443 allowed for my site, but when I write a TCP socket in Python that should work through port 443 or port 80, the OS tells me that I need to run the program from the user's root, but if I start the bot, then the OS does not swear at all about the rights and the bot works quietly. If I still decide to run a socket on port 443 or 80, then the OS replies that these ports are busy.

So, please explain to me why the telegram bot does not conflict with processes and ports?

My server is Ubuntu 22.04

P.S. I already asked this question on `stackexchange`, but as I understand it, they do not understand telegram bots, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... too much misunderstandings in your question. It will be better to understand basics of [TCP connection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0916/6ja85398n/index.html) and [NAT tables](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/nat.htm) first.

I will try to explain this situation in short

---

> when I write a TCP socket in Python that should work through port 443 or port 80, the OS tells me that I need to run the program from the user's root

1. 80 and 443 are [privileged ports](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) and Linux doesn't allow to use it under non-admin users. It has nothing to do with Nginx conflicts and [may be solved](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443) by proper configuration
2. If you will try to use non-privileged port like `8080` python may be executed even without admin permissions

---

> So, please explain to me why the telegram bot does not conflict with processes and ports?

1. Nginx and Python socket are listening at `80` and `443` ports and waiting for incoming connections. You have to access your server IP to initiate connection
2. Telegram bot (and any another bot) are using Telegram servers to connect. Just imagine that you instantly looking in Telegram app and immediately answering on all messages. Bot doing the same stuff. It is just client for remote server (You don't need to listen `443` at your machine to be able use Telegram app, right?). It is listening no port and don't waiting for incoming connections but waiting for messages at remote server
3. But you can argue "Hey stop, but Python bot still connected to Telegram servers. What ports it uses? Isn't that is same as the socket?" → Here is the same TCP connection, but Python using **OUTGOING** dynamic ports to connect Telegram server's **INCOMING** static port `443`. Outgoing port may be `20323` or `27578` for example. It is all about **NAT**. In short any non-used port may be used to establish connection between remote `443` and local `XXXX` ports.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can you please tell me how to do this without using telegram bots, so that you can communicate with your python program on port 443 without running it as root, what libraries to use for this?

Comment: Right now you using Telegram server to be able communicate with your python app. Telegram server is `443` entry gate, connection point. If you don't use Telegram server you have to create own entry gate with static global IP and domain name like `my-service.com` (that is may be Python app using socket). How to run app without root permissions? I already linked [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443) about it. How to run app on port `443` if Nginx already using this port? Simply: It is not possible. Only one app may listen a port

Comment: However you may set proxy feature inside Nginx server and redirect all specific connections coming to Nginx's `443` to Python app's another port.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two things, I think.

nginx/apache/a python server process trying to *listen* on port 443 or 80 need to be run by root (or another user with elevated privilege levels).

A python bot trying to talk to a telegram server on port 443 doesn't have that limitations; browsers also don't need to run as root.

If this doesn't answer your question you need to be a bit clearer on what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but some questions remain. As I understand it, the telegram bot works through websockets, because it does not need to constantly send https requests to the telegram server in order to receive messages from users. What then happens under the hood if it is not listening on port 443? I want to understand how it works at the OS level, if you know in which direction to look for answers, then please tell me.